# Why can't I activate Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 Professional installed, however it is saying it is not a valid version, I then try to enter in my activation serial/key and I get the error messages shown in the screen shot below...

[image]

Any ideas why it is not accepting my valid serial/key?

Comment: Is this an upgrade or full version?

Comment: You could try activating by phone. That's worked for me with XP when I couldn't activate over the Internet because I'd already installed it on a another PC. Haven't tried it with Windows 7, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it *isn't* a valid version. You may have unknowingly bought a pirated copy. It happens more often than some might think--Bob's Computers down the street builds you a custom PC from over-the-counter parts and installs Windows on it without obtaining the proper license, for example.

How did you acquire this copy of Windows? Have you checked the [anti-piracy features](http://www.microsoft.com/howtotell/product.aspx?pID=38c37f36-bc93-4b47-b8a1-844b6968bc8e&cID=ea710cad-37b0-4975-bcd6-abfee19961df&method=oem&displaylang=en) to ensure that it's genuine?

Comment: Also, you can contact Microsoft if you DO bought it.

Comment: A quick call to MS will sort it out after you check the anti-piracy features. If you bought it froma well known supplier, MS should have you going quickly.

Comment: Call 1-888-725-1047(United States) to get it sorted out with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of possibilities. That specific message usually appears if you type the key in wrong, or have a key for the wrong product. For example, if you purchased Windows 7 Ultimate, you can't use that key with Windows 7 Professional. Where did your key come from? Did you buy Windows in a retail box, as an upgrade, with your computer...?